# Bug in pluralize and testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called TipoContato (table tipos_contato), if I pluralize this it will become tipo_contatos, so I added this to inflections:

```
inflect.irregular 'tipo_contato', 'tipos_contato'
```

OK, testing it in console it is perfect:

```
>> TipoContato
=> TipoContato(id: integer, descricao: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

But, when running test cases I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Table 'contacts_test.tipo_contatos' doesn't exist: DELETE FROM `tipo_contatos`
```

Trying to force rails to recognize my table I tried:

```
set_table_name 'tipos_contato'
```

And I got the very same error.

Rails 2.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's a bug, but there is a workaround. Change the name of the fixtures file to tipos_contato.yml. Next, wire this up in the unit test like so:

```
class TipoContatoTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  set_fixture_class :tipos_contato => TipoContato
  ...
end
```

Here's a [post](http://www.missiondata.com/blog/uncategorized/80/rails-fixtures-with-models-using-set_table_name/) that describes this in a bit more detail.